# TYPO3 TemplateService deprecation: how to get plugin typoscript? (NOT in FE context and WITHOUT extbase)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In V12 the `TemplateService` and `TypoScriptParser` classes have been marked as deprecated ([#99020 - Deprecate TypoScript/TemplateService](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.1/Deprecation-99020-DeprecateTypoScriptTemplateService.html)). The migration advice given there is very scarce (FE scope with PSR-7 request) and frankly unsatisfactory.

How can you read the TypoScript configuration of a plugin (something like `plugin.tx_myplugin_pi1 { ... }`), if you're *not* in FE context, e.g. in a middleware, console command or BE module? Sometimes you also want to read the TS config of a different extension.
And yes, I know, a plugin is a FE content element and is executed in the context of a specific page (for which there may be a series of inherited TS templates in the rootline) etc. etc.

But there are still valid scenarios where you need this. Let's say we have a console command that sends data generated by a plugin to a remote API and we want to process the data with the same settings that are active on the page, where the data is generated in the first place. If the console command has a command line parameter for the uid of that page, it shouldn't be a problem to get that specific TS configuration.

So far, I've used helper methods that might have looked something like this:

```
private function getTsConf($pageUid, $pluginName = 'tx_myplugin_pi1') {
    $rootlineUtility = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(RootlineUtility::class, $pageUid);
    $rootline = $rootlineUtility->get();

    $templateService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TemplateService::class);
    $templateService->tt_track = 0;
    $templateService->runThroughTemplates($rootline);
    $templateService->generateConfig();

    $tsService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoScriptService::class);
    return isset($templateService->setup['plugin.'][$pluginName.'.']) 
        ? $tsService->convertTypoScriptArrayToPlainArray($templateService->setup['plugin.'][$pluginName.'.']) 
        : [];
}
```

So what are you supposed to do in such a case, if `TemplateService` is no longer available?

For me, this is a problem I seem to encounter in almost every project. I really think, this is a standard task that should be easy to deal with. But I feel there is a lack of documentation for non-FE scenarios.

Comment: (Preface: I haven't personally had to face that challenge yet, and I understand frustration)
  
Maybe it's an option to retriev relevant typoscript variables in another scope like Site Settings/YAML, global configuration? What would be a specific usage case, maybe approaching it a bit differently could lead to less complexity?  

  
Another idea would be to mock a frontend request, so that you actually have a PSR-7 $request with all its frontend context to operate on? That would really get you into the FE scope then and not need a separate manual bootstrap...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no factory to retrieve FE TS for a specific page.

The code in question has to be extracted from TypoScriptFrontendController, which needs an extraction of the 'cache' related stuff first. We'll continue to work on this in v13, but v12 will not have a simple solution.

I would have loved a couple more patches in this area for v12, but it was simply too much, given the time and release restrictions and lots of old code laying around. We're just now doing next steps in v13, I hope we'll end up with an easy to use API in v13 when lots of surrounding dust has settled as well.

I see these alternatives in v12:

- When doing a FE request from within BE or CLI, create a request object, feed it to Frontend/Application (that's called a sub request, the FE error handling and FE functionals tests do similar things) to retrieve a Response. This will trigger the entire FE chain including TS calculations.
- Use extbase ConfigurationManager to retrieve FE TS. ConfigurationManager is a technical debt itself, but it's hard to get rid of it and will continue to stay for a while after we mitigated some of it's flaws in v12.
- Use old deprecated TS class in v12 and switch to a better solution with v13.
- Copy code from TypoScriptFrontendController getFromCache() to your extension, maybe streamline / shorten it a bit, when you don't need so complex cache mechanics. It's longish, but well documented ... it should be possible to follow and understand by looking at it.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed (and honest) answer! I guess I'll stick with TemplateService for the time being and keep my fingers crossed for a better solution in v13. The use of ConfigurationManager has previously been discouraged in non-extbase context; the getFromCache() method is marked with "method may vanish from TypoScriptFrontendController without further notice" and makes use of TemplateService as well, so no real benefit there.

Comment: Any news on this for v13? I'm in need to use TS in v13 but did not find a solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to generate needed TypoScript when in BE or CLI context. This works in v12 and v13 but is not fully tested in production yet. Feedback welcome!

```
protected function generateTypoScript(int $pid, ServerRequestInterface $request): array
{
    $siteFinder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class);
    $site = $siteFinder->getSiteByPageId($pid);

    $controller = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
        TypoScriptFrontendController::class,
        GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class),
        $site,
        $site->getDefaultLanguage(),
        new PageArguments($site->getRootPageId(), '0', []),
        GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendUserAuthentication::class)
    );

    // @extensionScannerIgnoreLine
    $controller->id = $pid;
    $controller->determineId($request);

    return $controller->getFromCache($request)->getAttribute('frontend.typoscript')->getSetupArray();
}
```

See here for a complete example hot to use it:
https://github.com/fnagel/generic-gallery/commit/0f1e60fe2ba65e4e3f494a0017aaca956c77f784

Comment: I've come across (and used) this approach as well, but as I said in my comment to @christian-kuhn: up and until v12 getFromCache() in TypoScriptFrontendController uses an instance of TemplateService as well + has comments like "@deprecated since v12, will be removed in v13: b/w compat. Remove when TemplateService is dropped"; the method itself was marked "may vanish from TypoScriptFrontendController without further notice" and in v13 it seems to have gone (at least according to the latest core source); I therefore don't see, how this can work? (haven't tested it myself though)